# How can I get module "remote_tag" in Python?

Tags: python, nltk, text-mining

There is a example in page 203 of [Python Text Processing with NLTK 2.0 Cookbook](https://www.packtpub.com/application-development/python-text-processing-nltk-20-cookbook) that imports the module `remote_tag`. But I didn't find any site that can download the module. How can I get module `remote_tag` in Python?

```
>>> import execnet, remote_tag, nltk.tag, nltk.data
>>> from nltk.corpus import treebank
>>> import cPickle as pickle
>>> tagger = pickle.dumps(nltk.data.load(nltk.tag._POS_TAGGER))
>>> gw = execnet.makegateway()
>>> channel = gw.remote_exec(remote_tag)
>>> channel.send(tagger)
>>> channel.send(treebank.sents()[0])
>>> tagged_sentence = channel.receive()
>>> tagged_sentence == treebank.tagged_sents()[0]
True
>>> gw.exit()
```

Comment: That appears to be five lines of code, that is also included in the book. See **How it works...** under the **Distributed tagging with execnet** section of chapter 8 (no page numbers on Google Books, I'm afraid!)

Answer (score 0):

create our own **remote_tag.py** module by following five lines of code that from page 204 of **Python Text Processing with NLTK 2.0 Cookbook** and place in the same directory as the program that we import it in.

```
    import cPickle as pickle

    if __name__ == '__channelexec__':
       tagger = pickle.loads(channel.receive())

       for sentence in channel:
         channel.send(tagger.tag(sentence))
```